# hola, estoy empezando en html, y tengo una inflexion que no me permite avanzar, y es esta parte del codigo: <img src=<" imagenes/descarga.jpg"/>

Tags: html

<img src=<" imagenes/descarga.jpg"/> en la pagina correspondiente al codigo deberia salir una imagen( la descargada ) pero en ese caso, me sale lo siguiente:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/30glN.png

Answer (score 3):

la sintaxis está mal, la sintaxis correcta sería

```
<img src="imagenes/descarga.jpg" alt="imagen X">
```

Siempre es importante declarar el alt="" si bien no evita que aparezca tu imagen, este generalmente se agrega por semántica y por las herramientas para las herramientas de accesibilidad, en el se pone una descripción de lo que es la imagen, ej: alt="logo de la empresa".

Te dejo link de documentación por si tienes alguna duda ahí hay ejemplos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Buena jornada!

Comment: Si puedes da la pregunta como cerrada, servirá para que otras personas sepan que se solucionó, tienes que hacerlo en la respuesta que consideres más adecuada. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Está mal la sintaxis, es

```
<img src="imagenes/descarga.jpg"/>
```